# How to output video to a texture in Java?

Tags: java, video, textures

I need to put video playback to my game, and the video must be in a texture so that it is played inside the game world.

I am using Java (Java3D, JOGL). Any idea on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Decode the video using whatever codec you need (in Java this may require JNI). Copy the output data, which is typically some buffer of pixel data, to a texture. Repeat at the desired framerate.